# Combine texts and calculate average

Tags: excel, vba, average

[image]

In excel, I can use & operator to combine the two cells as shown in the attached picture and use average to calculate the average of all the cells in yellow cycle.
How can I do that in VBA?

I would like the text combination code and the average code follow my written code as shown below

```
Sub emasummarytest()

'Matching the investment cycle in the summary output with the data
Dim stx, edx As Integer

For y = 4 To 6102
    
    If IsError(Application.Match(Cells(y, 25), Range("P:P"), 0)) Then
    
    Else
    'finding the location
        stx = Application.Match(Cells(y, 25), Range("P:P"), 0) 'starting location
        edx = Application.Match(Cells(y, 25), Range("P:P"), 1) 'ending location
    
    'do certain tasks
        Cells(y, 26) = "50,200" 'display the strategy
        Cells(y, 27) = Application.Count(Range(Cells(stx, 16), Cells(edx, 16))) 'number of days in each cycle
        Cells(y, 28) = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(stx, 7), Cells(edx, 7))) 'cummulative daily return
        Cells(y, 29) = Cells(y, 28) / Cells(y, 27) 'average daily return
        Cells(y, 30) = ((1 + Cells(y, 29)) ^ 250) - 1 'annualised daily return
    End If
    
Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: The ampersand works in VBA as well... give it a shot.

Comment: thank you and how about average?

Comment: `application.average()` also works... you've gotta just give it a shot sometimes and if you get specific issues, that's a bit better.